# Are partitial differential operators commutative?

Tags: partial-derivative

I am trying to convert $\Delta=\nabla^2 = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}$ to polar coordinates. If anyone has any references on how to do that I would appreciate it.

In my evaluation, I am messing with a lot of partials. Alghough, I am not sure as to if partials are commutative, and google has not been helping me. Enough of a prompt; is this true?
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}
$$
In the previous equation I just switched the denominators.

Comment: If you just want the answer, [Wikipedia has it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates) (look at cylindrical and remove the $z$ part).  And no, $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}\color{red}{\ne}\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$$ in general.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all: you cannot just switch the denominators like that.

Partial derivatives *kind of* commute, but not in the sense you are implying. Suppose I have a function $f(x,y)$. Then it *is* the case that

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(x,y) = \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,y)
$$

The partial derivatives commute in this particular case since $x,y$ are independent. That is, $\partial x/\partial y = \partial y/\partial x = 0$.

It is not the case, however, that arbitrary partial derivatives commute. For example, if we were to introduce $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$, then the partials would *not* commute.

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} f(x,y) \ne \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,y)
$$

It also isn't the case that partial derivatives commute with functions. For example

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,y) g(x,y) \ne f(x,y) \frac{\partial}{\partial x} g(x,y)
$$

To compute gradients and other vector calculus operations in different coordinate systems, you need to use the [multivariate chain rule](https://math.hmc.edu/calculus/hmc-mathematics-calculus-online-tutorials/multivariable-calculus/multi-variable-chain-rule/).

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the "Polar Laplacian".  Googling "Polar Laplacian Derivation" leads to many papers such as [this one](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~saito/courses/21C.w11/polar-lap.pdf) that go through step-by-step with how to derive it.

If after reading this you're still interested in a challenge, try deriving the Laplacian for Spherical or Cylindrical coordinates.